# What does "pending publication" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, ambiguity

When you have submitted a manuscript to a publisher, and the publisher is still reviewing it to see whether they should publish it or not. Does that mean that your manuscript is pending review or pending publication. 
Pending can be defined as Undecided or Imminent so it's really confusing.

Comment: If the MS is still being reviewed, it is *in review*.

Comment: It is pending both, as well as a vast number of other things. There is nothing confusing about it at all. Anything at all that can happen to it, but hasn't happened yet, that anything is still pending. Publication, review, rejection, fire, praise, being framed and being used as toilet paper, it is pending all these things.

Answer (score 5):

*Pending publication* is a later stage than *pending review*.

Once the editor of the journal thinks the manuscript is worth being reviewed, he dispatches it to the referees. From this moment until the decision letter is issued, the state of the manuscript should be *Pending review*.

Once the decision letter states that the manuscript has been accepted for publication (maybe after revisions, so it will be the last decision letter), the state of the manuscript becomes *Pending publication*. This usually corresponds to that short period allowed for proofreading and typographical adjustments.